# Python3 waiting for all async threads to finish

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous

I need to start between 64 and 256 network tests which take a different amount of time each (most of them between 10 and 30 seconds).

I simply use a system("network_code file target") on debian. It works but it is slow as hell since each call waits for the next one to finish.

in C++ I would do something like

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 256;i++)
{
 system("network_app");
}
```

which is still incredible stupid, but at least 16x times faster than doing it one by one.

How can you start X async threads in Python in parallel and wait until all have finished?

```
my_hosts = [...]

for host in my_hosts:
 execute_in_parallel(system("network_app " + host + " > " + host + ".dump"))

wait_until_are_all_jobs_are_finished()
```

Comment: what did you try ? `threading.Thread()` runs code in separated thread and it has `join()` to wait for end of threads. Only problem that Python has GIL which blocks threads. But similar way should work [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 0):

I used threading to solve the problem, since my commands where IO Bound (long waiting time for disk access). Don't use this for compute bound problems, use in this case numby.

```
import threading

def my_function(argument1, argument2):
 with open(argument1+"."+argument2, "r") as my_file:
 a = 1
 #do some stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":

threadlist = []

 for i in range (100):
    t = threading.Thread(target=my_function, args=(argument1,argument2))
    threadlist.append(t)

    for thread in threadlist:
        thread.start()
        
    for thread in threadlist:
        thread.join()
```